# PHP password_verify Returning False When Retrieving Hashed PW from Database

Tags: php, wordpress, passwords, advanced-custom-fields, password-encryption

I've scoured the threads inside and outside of SO, but nothing has solved the issue.

Background: Creating a small login system with PHP, Wordpress, and ACF (Advanced Custom Fields).  Upon saving of the Post containing the Password, the password gets hashed, and the value replaced in the database.  So far so good (as far as I can tell).  When a user visits the login page, submits a password-attempt, the validation php file calls the Wordpress API, retrieves the stored-hashed PW, and then runs password_verify.  Every time this runs, it returns false. Code below...

```
    $pw_submit = $_POST['pw-submit'];

    //Call WP API
    $urlPrefix = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ?
    'https' : 'http';
    $siteURL = $urlPrefix . "://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    function callAPI($method, $url, $data){
        $curl = curl_init();
        $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));

        // OPTIONS:
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: 
            application/json'));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        // EXECUTE:
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
            curl_close($curl);
            return $result;
    }

    $get_data = callAPI('GET', $siteURL . '/wp-json/acf/v3/pages/25', false);
    $response = json_decode($get_data, true);
    $db_password = $response[acf][portal_password];        

    if( password_verify( $pw_submit, $db_password) ){
        echo "Well that worked";
    }
    else{
        echo "No it didn't";
    }
```

Even if I copy/paste the hashed password over and try to verify, it still returns false...

```
    $hash = '$2y$10$2/PuBIYuhEJ69fSc2/ae.OOVr4nMrpKu.9ahRm90TuSBu0EJulWki';
    $verify = password_verify('foobar', $hash);
    var_dump($verify);
```

...it returns bool(false).

The ONLY way password_verify ever returns true is if I create the hashed-password and verify it right away.  So in the validation script...

```
    $pw_hash = password_hash('foobar', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $verify = password_verify('foobar', $pw_hash);
    var_dump($verify); // Returns TRUE
```

I've checked the database and made sure the table cell is holding the entire hash (when I var_dump the pulled value, I get a 60 character string). I've made sure there are no empty spaces before/after by using trim().  I've tried replacing the containing double-quotes containing the hashed-string with single-quotes.  I have no idea what's missing/going wrong.  Any help/guidance is GREATLY appreciated.  Thanks!

**UPDATE**
So the error in this was that I had forgotten to update a variable when fixing a previous issue.  For those who might stumble upon this, the original issue was that Wordpress was running my hashing script twice, resulting in a hash of the first hashed password.  So always check what wordpress is actually doing.  Also, one thing I ran into was using the ACF get_field() to grab the unhashed password, but because I was using the wp_insert_post_data() filter, I was actually grabbing an old/current value, instead of getting the new/input password. Fixed this by using the 'acf/save_post' filter.  Thank you everyone for the help!

Comment: note `$db_password = $response[acf][portal_password];  ` should probably be `$db_password = $response['acf']['portal_password'];  `

Comment: `$2y$10$2/PuBIYuhEJ69fSc2/ae.OOVr4nMrpKu.9ahRm90TuSBu0EJulWki` is a valid hash for an empty string. If that's your real data, work out where it came from and fix the code that created it.

Comment: GrumpyCrouton thanks, I've confirmed the no-quotes works as desired.  @iainn I've tried all kinds of strings, but it only seems to verify-true if I create the hash right then and there.  I feel as though something is happening when pulling from the database, but can't figure out what, as I've tried sanitizing the string numerous ways.

Comment: My point is that the verification code you've posted here looks fine, but the hash stored in your database isn't what you think you have. Whatever it was that created that hash wasn't operating on the correct string - it's a valid bcrypt hash, but of an empty string. `var_dump(password_verify('', '$2y$10$2/PuBIYuhEJ69fSc2/ae.OOVr4nMrpKu.9ahRm90TuSBu0EJulWki'));
bool(true)`

Comment: @iainn sorry, I misunderstood your point.  you were right! I was hashing an empty string.  I realize now that over the last day, I had reworked my hashing script due to a different issue, and had missed a variable replace.  Thank you!  How do I mark your comment as correct? Want to make sure you get your internet points :)

Comment: @MHDavinci It may _work_ fine, I wasn't saying it wouldn't - however, it will raise a notice, and isn't properly written.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton appreciate the note.  I've updated the script per your suggestion to be more in line with best-practices.

Answer (score 0):

`$db_password = $response[acf][portal_password];` doesn't have properly formatted indexes. Use `$db_password = $response['acf']['portal_password'];` instead.

Because of this error, `password_verify($pw_submit, $db_password)` is verifying the users entered password with the variable `$db_password` which doesn't contain any information.

Comment: Unquoted array indices work fine in PHP, although they'll raise a notice/warning while doing do. It wouldn't cause the variable to be any different.

Comment: Thanks Brxxn, have already confirmed that $db_password is receiving data (using a var_dump), but just to be sure I tried your suggestion, and same result, no dice. :(